# C++ Convert an HMODULE to two integers

Tags: c++

I have an x64 application that calls LoadLibrary, and I have to pass the resulting HMODULE as 2 integers  to a different application.

I thought of converting it to a string and, substring it to the two parts and then converting the result to ints.

I'm unable to turn it into a string, could you help?

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: An `HMODULE` in one application won't be valid in another application as they have different virtual memory layouts, and an `HMODULE` is basically a pointer. You can't share pointers between processes.

Comment: @HansPassant, I cannot disclosed the full details of my issue because of my work contract.

Comment: @interjay, I'm using "known" DLLs like ntdll and ole32, so their addresses are the same for all processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually what I did was use the [ULARGE_INTEGER struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) which has a "HighPart" and "LowPart" as follows:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER long_address;
long_address.QuadPart = (ULONGLONG)address;
fprintf(file, "%d,%d", long_address.HighPart, long_address.LowPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

guessing that the app want the upper and lower parts of the 64 bit handle - I am not sure if handles are 64 bits on 64 bit machine

```
uint left = (hmodule & 0XFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
uint right = (hmodule & 0XFFFFFFFF);
```

if handles are 32 bit

```
   uint left = (hmodule & 0XFFFF0000) >> 16;
    uint right = (hmodule & 0XFFFF);
```

for sure converting to string etc will not work

Comment: You're zeroing the relevant bits before shifting, so `left` will be 0. And you will need to cast to integer type first. But as I said in a comment above, the whole premise of this question is misguided.